# Is Redis good choice for performing large scale of calculations?

Tags: performance, oracle, grails, groovy, redis

Currently pulling large scale of data from the oracle database & then performing calculation on web side for generating HTML reports. I am using Groovy & Grails frame work for report generation.

Now the problem is , We are having very huge calculation & it takes lots of time to generate report on web side.

I am planning to re-architecture my reports , so it generate reports very quickly.

I don't have any command on ORACLE database as it's third-party production database.

I don't want any replication of the database , because it has millions of records , so can't schedule & replication it slow down the production.

I finally came up with some caching architecture , which perform like some calculation engine.

Anyone can help me by providing best solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. What is structure of your data? Do you want to query so SQL can help you, or is it binary/document?
2. Do you need persistence (durability) or not?

Redis is fast. But if you have single threaded app using MS SQL and their bulk importer, it's incredibly fast too.

Redis is key/value stores so you need to perform single `SET` for every column within your domain object, so it can be slower than any other RDBMS which uses `INSERT` along with all columns.

Or if your results are in form of JSON object, Mongo can be very useful.

It just depends on your data and purpose of persistence.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer.

Here is simple example..

I fetch a raw data for a year so ORACLE gives me millions of record , my web application perform algorithms & get the final result which turns out to be say not more than 50 rows & few columns.

I don't have any rights to perform anything with database , I meant i can't write views or procedures something like that.

Comment: 50 rows of structured data? I mean why did you choose Redis or not RDBMS like MySql?

Comment: 50 rows are like, lets say week wise. 

Currently , if there are 100 hits on a report , application will make calculation for 100 times

Comment: Well, I've asked for structure of one row. Still not understand why you chose nosql over sql.

Comment: Structure of data is :-

This row is after the calculation algorithm is executed

Type | WW1 | WW2 | WW3 | and so on...

Comment: This structure/schema is static or the number of column is dynamic according to results?

Comment: yup , it is dynamic..based on the range user has selected

Comment: Sounds for me that I would provide JSON persistence for your content and store it as document. Important here is if you want to provide a cache (using redis, means that all data are gone once you kill redis) or you want serious persistence. Seems like you does not need best features which redis beats the rest. See http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/7/6/11-common-web-use-cases-solved-in-redis.html

Comment: So for persistence data what would you suggest, mongodb?

Comment: When you work with document itself, no quering and relation decomposition required, so I do.